# Is there any plugin for jaxb in maven 3?

Tags: maven, jaxb, maven-3

Recently I have migrated my maven from maven2 to maven3.
I had a project where i was using **org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2** plugin.
When i did a `mvn clean install` in maven2 It was success.
But when i did the same in maven 3. I got the following exception

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:90)
>           at org.twdata.maven.mojoexecutor.MojoExecutor.executeMojo(MojoExecutor.java:88)
>           ... 24 more

I have searched a lot for jaxb plugin for maven 3. But i couldn't find one.
Whether this plugin is available for maven 3 ? Or any other solution for this ?

Comment: Your question is a contradiction in itself. Cause you searched and found but you say you couldn't find? I assume you mean you would like to know if this plugin [jaxb2-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/) is useable for Maven 3?

Comment: Sorry about the brief question. I have edited to elaborate.

Comment: Can you post the full error output not only excerpts.

Answer (score 0):

Do you search for this one? [JAXB-2 Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/)

I am not sure what exactly you are looking for... So i only guess and post some links. Please be more detailed next time :)

You should check these links:

- [Link one: javax.xml.bind » jaxb-api](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api)
- [Link two: javax.xml » jaxb-api](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml/jaxb-api)